# How do I make this angular2 service somewhat synchronous?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I have an angular2 service and I want it to do the following:

1. Ftp to remote server
2. Find a file read some lines from it
3. Build a 'results' json object and return to the calling component

So - actually I have steps 1 / 2 working - but of course its all 'async'. So what is happening is in my component I am doing this call to the service where `this.ftp` is the instance of my service:

```
 this.servers = this.ftp.lookForServers();
```

Now this correctly calls the lookForServers method of my FTP service , which looks like this:

```
lookForServers(){
    var servers = [];
    var whereAreWe = 0;
    var possibles = ["/path/to/servers/"];
    for(var i=0;i<possibles.length;i++){
      whereAreWe = i;
      this.c.list(possibles[i],false,(err,list)=>{
        for(var p=0;p<list.length;p++){
          console.log(list[p]);
          var server_version = this.grabLog(possibles[whereAreWe]+list[p].name);
          servers.push({
            name: list[p].name,
            path: possibles[whereAreWe]+list[p].name,
            version: server_version
          });
        }
      });
    }
    return servers;
   }
```

Now - the `this.grabLog(possibles[whereAreWe]+list[p].name);` function call ends up making further calls to the this.c - the FTP client, which of course is async, so this method returns almost immediately - whilst the callbacks continue to run. Those callbacks download a file, and then another callback function processes this file - again line by line, asynchronously picking out various details i want to store.

By the end of this chain - I have all my details in the final :

```
lineReader.on('close', () => { function - but of course my `this.ftp.lookForServers();` function call has long gone....and the component is none the wiser.
```

So how can I let this work happen asynchronously, and still pass back to the component my results JSON object once the work is complete? This is probably quite a simple question about how do I make a service call a component callback...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need it to run syncronously. You should make lookForServers (and the other function it's using) use observables, then subscribe to the result like this:

```
this.ftp.lookForServers().subscribe((data) => {  this.servers = data });
```

Here are the implementations:

```
const Client = require('ftp');
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

import { NextObserver } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

interface server {
    name: string;
    path: string;
    version: string;
    java_version: string;
}

export class FTPClient {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    host: string;
    port: number;
    c: any;

    constructor() {
    }

    init(username, password, host, port) {
        console.log("initiating FTP connection to:" + host + "on port:" + port);

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.c = new Client();

        console.log("Client created");
    }

    connect() {
        console.log("About to start connection");

        this.c.on('ready', () => {
            this.c.list((err: any, list: any) => {
                if (err) throw err;

                console.dir(list);
                this.c.end();
            });
        });

        // connect to localhost:21 as anonymous
        var connectProps = {
            host : this.host,
            port : this.port,
            user : this.username,
            password : this.password
        };

        console.log("Connecting now...");
        this.c.connect(connectProps);
    }

    public lookForServers(name: string): Observable<any[]> {
        return Observable.create((observer: NextObserver <any[]>) => {
            let servers = [];
            let whereAreWe = 0;
            let possibles = [ "/path/to/servers/" ];

            for (var i = 0; i < possibles.length; i++) {
                whereAreWe = i;

                this.c.list(possibles[ i ], false, (err: any, list: any) => {
                    for (var p = 0; p < list.length; p++) {
                        this.grabMessagesLog(possibles[ whereAreWe ] + list[ p ].name)
                        .subscribe((data: any) => {
                                let server_version = data;

                                servers.push({
                                    name : list[ p ].name,
                                    path : possibles[ whereAreWe ] + list[ p ].name,
                                    version : server_version
                                });

                                observer.next(servers);
                                observer.complete();
                            }
                        );
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    grabMessagesLog(path): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.create((observer: NextObserver <any>) => {
            let result = '';
            let unix = Math.round(+new Date() / 1000);
            this.c.binary(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });

            this.c.get(path + "/logs/messages.log", (err, stream) => {
                if (err) throw err;

                stream.once('close', () => {
                    this.c.end();
                    this.getServerMetadataFromMessagesLog(unix + "_messages.log")
                    .subscribe((data) => {
                        stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(unix + "_messages.log"));

                        observer.next(data);
                        observer.complete();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }

    getServerMetadataFromMessagesLog(path): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.create((observer: NextObserver <any>) => {
            let lineReader = readline.createInterface({
                input : fs.createReadStream(path)
            });

            let server_version = "";
            let java_version = "";
            let line_no = 0;

            lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
                line_no++;
                console.log("line number is:" + line_no);

                if (line.includes("STUFF") && line.includes("FLAG2") && line_no == 2) {
                    var first = line.split("FLAG2")[ 1 ];
                    var last = first.split(" (")[ 0 ];
                    var version = "FLAG2" + last;
                    this.server_version = version;
                    console.log("version is:" + version);
                }

                if (line.includes("java.version =")) {
                    var javav = line.split("java.version =")[ 1 ];
                    this.java_version = javav;
                    lineReader.close();
                }

                console.log('Line from file:', line);
            });

            lineReader.on('close', () => {
                var res = {
                    version : server_version,
                    java_version : java_version
                };

                alert("RES IS:" + JSON.stringify(res));

                observer.next(res);
                observer.complete();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so whenever you subscribe whatever you return from the other callback is pulled back into the subscribed callback?

Comment: Yes. When you do .subscribe((data), 'data' is 'any[]' because the function returns Observable<any[]>.

Comment: where do i import Observable and NextObserver from?

Comment: import { NextObserver } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

Comment: As much as this looks like the right way to go - its beginning to look complicated - and somewhat of a mess of callbacks and Observables which is confusing code to read. Maybe ill try the recursive timeout method below

Comment: What's so complicated about it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128292/discussion-between-boyan-kostadinov-and-renegadeandy).

Answer (score 1):

Try using a **recursive** function with the [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout#!) function of Angular

```
function recursiveWait(server_version){

    if(server_version != null){
        return;
    }

    $timeout(function(){recursiveWait()}, 500);
}
```

And place it here:

```
      console.log(list[p]);
      var server_version = this.grabLog(possibles[whereAreWe]+list[p].name);
      recursiveWait(server_version);
      servers.push({
        name: list[p].name,
```

This will ask the var if it's `!= null` If it's equal it will call the function again in **500ms**, if it's not it will return and exit the function, letting the code continue.

Comment: except server_version will *always* be null as the function this.grabLog returns almost immediately as the rest of that code runs async...so i assume i would want to check for some kind of variable which each of the callbacks has a context of, and wait for that to != null? Also I think the function timeout call should be "recursiveWait - not recursiveF"?

Comment: server_version will be, at some time, != than null. So that recursive function will wait to that change.An Async function will make a **time out** in js and force the null return. But the code keeps working and when finish, return the value.

Comment: My concern is this is one attempt after 500ms another and it's all timing based - which very well could fail based upon speed of processor and network. I know I can increase this timeout but still seems somewhat 'shaky' as a solution? Is there any alternative approaches?

Comment: Why would you do this?! Just subscribe to the async call. See my answer.

Comment: The function can return the value at any time and it will never touch again the var. So when it's ready the next recursive call will see this and exit.

Comment: The answer applies to A1, while the question considers A2 (it was mistakenly tagged with `angularjs`).